# Return the range of a dataframe not within a range of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following main dataframe:

```
first.seqnames  first.start first.end   first.width first.strand    second.seqnames second.start    second.end  second.width    second.strand
0   chr1    346212  346975  7   *   chr1    10882   10888   7   *
1   chr1    3135476 3136100 2   *   chr1    10890   10891   2   *
2   chr1    11473   11484   12  *   chr1    10893   10904   12  *
3   chr1    5388140 5388730 2   *   chr1    11096   11097   2   *
4   chr1    346213  346984  68  *   chr1    11202   11269   68  *
```

I want to return the rows of above dataframe that don't exist within the range of the following dataframe:

```
first.seqnames  first.start first.end   3   4   5
3503    chr1    346213  346984  .   0   .
3504    chr1    3135466 3136202 .   0   .
3505    chr1    3190760 3191377 .   0   .
3506    chr1    3354604 3355258 .   0   .
3507    chr1    5388136 5388749 .   0   .
```

Here, the first dataframe's 'first.start' and 'first.end' should not exist within the range(346213, 346984),.......

I've tried the following code which creates memory and time complexity. Even the result isn't accurate. Here, some of the df1 ranges exist exactly between the df2 ranges and some overlaps. In case of overlaps, the ranges can be ignored.

```
def range_subset(range1, range2):
    """Whether range1 is a subset of range2."""
    if not range1:
        return True  # empty range is subset of anything
    if not range2:
        return False  # non-empty range can't be subset of empty range
    if len(range1) > 1 and range1.step % range2.step:
        return False  # must have a single value or integer multiple step
    return range1.start in range2 and range1[-1] in range2

for a,b in zip(df1['first.start'], df1['first.end']):
    for i,j in zip(df2['first.start'], df2['first.end']):
        if(range_subset(range(a, b), range(i, j)) == True):
            print(a,b)
```

Output:

```
first.seqnames  first.start first.end   first.width first.strand    second.seqnames second.start    second.end  second.width    second.strand
0   chr1    346212  346975  7   *   chr1    10882   10888   7   *
2   chr1    11473   11484   12  *   chr1    10893   10904   12  *
```

Comment: Will both dataframes have the same lengths?

Comment: @richardec No, df1 has more rows than df2

Comment: How do you determine which row of `df2` to use for a given row from `df1`?

Comment: @richardec I want to exclude the df1 ranges that fall between df2 ranges. df2 has no other purposes.

Comment: Based on those two dataframes, will you please provide a sample expected output dataframe? It would help me a lot :)

Comment: @richardec Output has been added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242282/discussion-between-md-abrar-jahin-and-richardec).

Comment: Is the range inclusive? (So if `df1`'s `first.start` was `346213`, would it match or not?)

Comment: @richardec Yeah, the range is inclusive here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the tuple pairs from the `(df1['first.start'], df1['first.end']) and (df2['first.start'], df2['first.end'])` initially in order to apply the range() function. After that, I put a condition whether `df1_ranges` are in the ranges of `df2_ranges` or not. Here the edge case was `df1['first.start'] = df1['first.end']`. I collected the filtered indices from the iterations and then passed into the df1.

```
df2_lst=[]
for i,j in zip(temp_df2['first.start'], temp_df2['first.end']):
    df2_lst.append(i)
    df2_lst.append(j)
df1_lst=[]
for i,j in zip(df1['first.start'], df1['first.end']):
    df1_lst.append(i)
    df1_lst.append(j)

def range_subset(range1, range2):
    """Whether range1 is a subset of range2."""
    if not range1:
        return True  # empty range is subset of anything
    if not range2:
        return False  # non-empty range can't be subset of empty range
    if len(range1) > 1 and range1.step % range2.step:
        return False  # must have a single value or integer multiple step
    return range1.start in range2 and range1[-1] in range2

##### FUNCTION FOR CREATING CHUNKS OF LISTS ####
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i],lst[i+1]

df1_lst2 = list(chunks(df1_lst,2))
df2_lst2 = list(chunks(df2_lst,2))
indices=[]
for idx,i in enumerate(df1_lst2): #main list
    x,y = i
    for j in df2_lst2: #filter list
        m,n = j
        if((x!=y) & (range_subset(range(x,y), range(m,n)))): #checking if the main list exists in the filter range or not
            indices.append(idx) #collecting the filtered indices

df1.iloc[indices]
```