# Efficient way of splitting or deleting the dataframe rows based on range filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 dataframes of unequal lengths among which the 1st one's rows will be filtered based on the ranges of the 2nd dataframe. For the better context of the I/O, please refer to this post:
[Efficient solution of dataframe range filtering based on another ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256653/efficient-solution-of-dataframe-range-filtering-based-on-another-ranges/71258525?noredirect=1#comment125960345_71258525)

For example:

```
M = (x,y) = [(10,20), (10,20), (10,20), (10,20), (10,20), (10,20)]
E = (m,n) = [(5,7), (15,16), (15,18), (21,25), (5,25), (5,15)]

Case-1: 
    M = [(10,20)]
    E = [(5,7)]
out: M = [(10,20)] (no change, because out of E range)

Case-2: 
    M = [(10,20)]
    E = [(15,16)]
out: M = [(10,14),(17,20)] (split (10,20) into 2 rows to remove E range inside it)

Case-3: 
    M = [(10,20)]
    E = [(21,25)]
out: M = [(10,20)] (no change, because out of E range)

Case-4: 
    M = [(10,20)]
    E = [(5,25)]
out: M = [] (delete because totally inclusive within range of E)

Case-5: 
    M = [(10,20)]
    E = [(5,15)]
out: M = [(16,20)] (because (16,20) isn't E range inclusive)

Case-6: 
    M = [(10,20)]
    E = [(13,20)]
out: M = [(10,12)] (because (10,12) isn't E range inclusive)
```

I have formulated the following algorithm for the above-stated cases:

```
M = (x,y) 
E = (m,n) 
if (m<=x): 
    if(y<=n):
        delete the row
    elif (x<=n):
        (start, end) = (n+1,y)
    else:
        continue
else:
    if(y>=n):
        (start, end) = (x,m-1)
        (start, end) = (n-1,y)
    elif (y>=m):
        (start, end) = (x,m-1)
    else:
        continue
```

But I wanted to implement it using NumPy and pandas combination:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('a.tsv', sep='\t') #main dataframe which I want to filter
temp_bed = bedfile # 2nd dataframe based on which I need to filter
# for array broadcasting
m = temp_bed['first.start'].to_numpy()[:, None]
n = temp_bed['first.end'].to_numpy()[:, None]

# A chunk_size that is too small or too big will lower performance.
# Experiment to find a sweet spot
chunk_size = 100_000
offset = 0
mask = []

while offset < len(df1):
    x = df1['first.start'].to_numpy()[offset:offset+chunk_size] #main
    y = df1['first.end'].to_numpy()[offset:offset+chunk_size]
    mask.append(
# necessary logical conditions #####
# but the problem is with splitting the rows or ranges
        ((m <= x) & (n >= y)).any(axis=0)
    )    

    offset += chunk_size
import numpy as np
mask = np.hstack(mask)
df1[mask]
```

**Could anyone give me an efficient solution for splitting or deleting or ignoring the dataframe rows based on the above conditions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case can be solved using *Numpy* and *Pandas* together.

To get results for all your cases, I extended *M* and *E* by one pair:

```
M = [(10,20), (10,20), (10,20), (10,20), (10,20), (10,20), (10,20)]
E = [( 5, 7), (15,16), (15,18), (21,25), ( 5,25), ( 5,15), (13,20)]
```

To get result, both as a list and a sequence of pairs (ranges of consecutive
numbers, inclusive), you can run:

```
for m1, m2, e1, e2 in np.hstack([M, E]):
    s = pd.Index(np.arange(m1, m2 + 1)).difference(pd.Index(
        np.arange(e1, e2 + 1))).to_series()
    rng = s.groupby(s.subtract(s.shift()).gt(1).cumsum()).apply(
        lambda grp: (grp.iloc[0], grp.iloc[-1]))
    print(f'{m1:2}, {m2:2},  {e1:2}, {e2:2}\n{s.tolist()}\n{rng.values}\n')
```

For the above source data I got:

```
10, 20,   5,  7
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[(10, 20)]

10, 20,  15, 16
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[(10, 14) (17, 20)]

10, 20,  15, 18
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20]
[(10, 14) (19, 20)]

10, 20,  21, 25
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[(10, 20)]

10, 20,   5, 25
[]
[]

10, 20,   5, 15
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[(16, 20)]

10, 20,  13, 20
[10, 11, 12]
[(10, 12)]
```

Each 3-rows sequence contains:

- original data (a pair from *M* and a pair from *E*),
- the result as a list of numbers,
- the result as a sequence of ramges.